# Error handling on VBScript: Not throwing error

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, adsutil.vbs

If error occured then it's going to sub DisplayCustomError but it's not throwing exception.
Expected result - After objHTTP.send (json) it should throw exception message. I have tried Call Err.Raise but it's not throwing anything. The code is in VBscript

```
 sub run
 On Error Resume Next
    wrapper.getVariable( "Plant_Price_PerKW" ).value = excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$331" )
    wrapper.getVariable( "Net_Present_Value" ).value = excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$782" )
    wrapper.getVariable( "IRR" ).value = excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$783" )
 Dim strMessage
    If Err.Number <> 0 And excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$783" ) = "" Then
     strMessage = "IRR cannot be computed. "
     DisplayCustomError(strMessage)
     WScript.Quit 
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 And (excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$783" ) <> "") Then
     strMessage = "Other Outputs cannot be computed."
     DisplayCustomError(strMessage)
     WScript.Quit 
    End If
end sub

Sub DisplayCustomError(strMessage)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim errorMessage, objHTTP, URL, json, errorCode, uniqueId, networkInfo, jobId
    errorMessage ="Error while executing EVMLite. Error number " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Source & strMessage
    errorCode = "ERR-1004"
    uniqueId = wrapper.getVariable("UniqueId").value
    Set networkInfo = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 
    jobId = networkInfo.ComputerName
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
    URL = "http://10.93.244.224343:9005/vpp/logerror"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    json = "{""jobId"": """& jobId &""", ""uniqueId"": """& uniqueId &""", ""errorCode"": """& errorCode &""", ""errorMessage"": """& errorMessage &"""}"
    'MsgBox json
    objHTTP.send (json)

    On Error Goto 0

    Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 10, "EVM Failed to execute", errorMessage)
    'MsgBox objHTTP.ResponseText

 End If
end sub
```

Comment: You are using `On Error Resume Next` which makes it ignore errors. remove that.

Comment: @braX I tried to remove On Error Resume NextSub and it's throwing the exception but it's not going into sub DisplayCustomError(strMessage) and when I am running second time then it's going to sub DisplayCustomError(strMessage)

Comment: Find a way to test for the condition that is causing whatever error you are getting and then use an if statement to avoid getting the error. Depending on errors happening is a bad way to be writing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The funny thing about VBScript's implementation of `On Error` is that it is not global - it is actually restricted by scope. So, if you apply `On Error Resume Next` in a Sub or Function and then enter a new Function or Sub that turns it off, that setting gets reverted when the Sub or Function exits.

In your case, your `Sub run` sets `On Error Resume Next` and it then calls `Sub DisplayCustomError` which sets `On Error GoTo 0`. That only applies *while you're still inside* `DisplayCustomError`. When it exits due to `Err.Raise`, your `Sub run` will carry on, because in that scope, it's still set to `On Error Resume Next`.

You will need to explicitly state `On Error GoTo 0` *within* `Sub run` before you make the call to `DisplayCustomError`

Here's an example VBS file you can test. If you run this, nothing will be thrown and the program will show the message "Done". If you uncomment the line in `Sub1`, then it'll raise the error "Example 2".

```
Sub Sub1()
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 1, "Example 1"
    'On Error Goto 0
    Sub2
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
    On Error Goto 0
    Err.Raise 2, "Example 2"
End Sub

Sub1
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: I have put On Error Goto 0 and Call Err.Raise before DisplayCustomError(strMessage) and removed  WScript.Quit. Now it's working and it's throwing error that I want. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar You're very welcome! Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick below the voting buttons. :)